# How to solve error compiling an arduino sketch?

Tags: arduino-uno

when I try to compile my Arduino UNO sketches using the official latest version Arduino software on Windows 7, I get this error

```
sketch\sketch_may21a.ino.cpp:1:21: fatal error: Arduino.h: No such file or directory
#include <Arduino.h>
                 ^
compilation terminated.
exit status 1
Error compiling for board Arduino/Genuino Uno.
```

what is the solution? What should i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know it's been a while but it might be helpful for other people.
I Solved my problem by doing the following from [arduino forums](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=362507.0):

1. Close the Arduino IDE
2. Go the the folder below:

   For **Mac OS X**:

   - /Users/(username)/Library/Arduino15

   For **Windows**:

   - Arduino IDE 1.6.5r5 and previous:
     C:\Users(username)\AppData\Roaming\Arduino15
   - Arduino IDE 1.6.6 and later:
     C:\Users(username)\AppData\Local\Arduino15
3. Delete the Arduino15 Folder
4. Reinstall the IDE.

Step 4 was not necessary for me, but if you messed with the libs, you should do a clean install.

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: I suppose for GNU/Linux, steps 2-4 would be  `rm -rf ~/.arduino15`

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this problem. so what I did is, GO to Device manager select the Arduino port COM.. .disable by click right, unplug & replug the Arduino, go to device manager select the Arduino port COM.. right click Enable that. then try. I hope that will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

Most `exit status 1 Error compiling` for board Arduino/Genuino Uno error comes if you don't have libraries for the header.

Solution is to download libraries and add to directory:
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Arduino\libraries